# .Net: Which one has better performance: setting image property of one control in design time or in run time?

Tags: .net, winforms, image, runtime

Which one has better performance?

setting image property of one control in design-time or in run-time?

Comment: How difficult is it to benchmark this?

Comment: Using what? Winforms? Web forms? WPF? Silverlight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing it at designtime will often just create code that ends up doing it in runtime. So should be about equal.

Comment: Agreed.  Only variable would be how the image is loaded.  Design time resources are stored in the DLL.  The OP doesn't state where the other image would be loaded from.  Either way, I'd expect this effect to be negligible unless perhaps thousands of these controls are being used (in which case perhaps it shouldn't be a control anyway.)